# Printing array variables

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a script as below:

```
$x=1;
$y=2;
@test=($x,$y);

foreach (@test)
{
 print;
 print "\n";
}
```

It gives me the output as:

1
2

BUT I want the output to be associated with placeholder, like:

$x = 1
$y = 2

Can somebody please provide some hints?

Comment: What is your question? How to print the strings `$x =` and `$y =`?

Comment: There's no relation between `$test[0]` and `$x`

Answer (score 3):

You don't put *variables* into an array; it contains *values* instead. When you assign a variable, or put it into an array, this value gets *copied*. We can demonstrate this:

```
$x = 1;
$y = $x; # here a copy
$x = 42; # reassigns $x, does not change $y
print "$x\n"; # 42
print "$y\n"; # 1
```

The same things happens when we put `$x` and `$y` into the array: It now contains the previous values only. There is no way to find out which variables they came from.

An *array* is a numbered collection of things. There is another interesting data structure: a *hash*. Hashes are underdered collections of things with labels. We can use a label to access the value `$hash{$label}`, much like we can access a thing in an array by its index `$array[$index]`.

The `keys` function returns a list of all labels of a hash, and the `sort` function orders a list alphabetically.

We can create a hash like

```
%hash = (
   x => $x, # the label "x" has the value of $x, but copied
   y => $y,
);
```

Now we can print all that out like

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) {
  print "$_ = $hash{$_}\n";
}
```

But because we write modern Perl, we `use strict; use warnings;`, declare all our variables, and `use 5.010` (or higher, because out perl is not completely outdated, so we can use the `say` function). Then we can do:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

my $x = 1;
my $y = 2;
my %hash = (
  x => $x,
  y => $y,
);

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
  say "$key = $hash{$key}"; # say is like print, but adds a newline
}
```

Output:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %test = ( x => '1',
             y => '2');

while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%test) ) {
        print "$key => $value\n";
    }
```

Output:

```
y => 2
x => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2684591

as the question points to array -

```
$x=1;
$y=2;
@test=($x,$y);

for my $i (0 .. $#test) {
    print "\$test[$i]: $test[$i]\n";
}
```